# Erro ao validar login em React Native

Tags: formulário, react-native

Tenho um app React Native que está me retornando um erro na busca por e-mail e senha.
Quando coloco o e-mail e a senha correta funciona normalmente, porém se eu colocar o e-mail e a senha errada, ele me retorna um erro e não é mostrado o `Alert.alert()`.
Uso o sequelize ORM.

O erro que ocorre é este:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data.dados[0].email')

A minha Função App ficou assim:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

axios.get('http://localhost:4000/listar/'+ email +'&'+ senha)
    .then((response) => {
        let emailBusca = response.data.dados[0].email;
        let senhaBusca = response.data.dados[0].senha;

        setEmail(emailBusca);
        setSenha(senhaBusca);

        response ? navigation.navigate('Home') : Alert.alert("Dados Incorretos!");
        
    }
);
```

O Api ficou assim:

```
const email = req.params.email;
const senha = req.params.senha;

const where = {
      email: email,
      senha: senha
  }

await TAB_USUARIOS.findAll({ where: where })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
            console.log('Dados: ' + response);
            return res.json({
                erro: 'false',
                dados: response,
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Erro: Tente mais tarde!');
            return res.json({
                erro: 'true',
                mensagem: 'Erro: Tente mais tarde!',
            });
        }
  }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Erro: Tente mais tarde!');
        return res.json({
            erro: 'true',
            mensagem: 'Erro: Tente mais tarde!',
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é que na resposta recebida por sua API, "dados" apenas vai existir se houver sucesso ao localizar o usuário. O seu response pode retornar "dados" e "erro" = false em caso de sucesso e "erro" = true e "mensagem" em caso de problemas.

Precisaria ajustar o consumo da API verificando se "erro" for false. Desta forma, você consegue redirecionar para a home em caso de sucesso ou mostrar alerta em caso de erro. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/listar/'+ email +'&'+ senha)
    .then((response) => {
        
        sucesso_login = false;
        if (response.data.erro == 'false'){
            let emailBusca = response.data.dados[0].email;
            let senhaBusca = response.data.dados[0].senha;
            sucesso_login = true;
            setEmail(emailBusca);
            setSenha(senhaBusca);
        }

        sucesso_login ? navigation.navigate('Home') : Alert.alert("Dados Incorretos!");
        
        }
);
```

Comment: Olá, amigo! Obrigada. Testei aqui, mas não funcionou:

Comment: let sucesso_login = false;
                
                if (response.data.dados.erro == 'true') {
                    sucesso_login = false;
                } else if (response.data.dados.erro == 'false') {
                    let emailBusca = response.data.dados[0].email;
                    let senhaBusca = response.data.dados[0].senha;
                    sucesso_login = true;
                }

Comment: Está dando Erro para as duas afirmativas.  Realmente eu fiz erro' false' para sucesso e erro 'true' para erro.